# Upgrade simulator to 7,1,2

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the latest xcode , Included iOS SDK: iOS 7.1 I but the app rejected cause it doesn't work with IOS 7.1.2

any idea how to upgrade the simulator to test on it

Comment: There isn’t a separate simulator for 7.1.2, just 7.1. Are you sure the problem is with 7.1.2 in particular, rather than with a specific device or configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking for updates on your simulator, although I am not sure if there was one for 7.1.2

[image]

Why not test on a device though? You should be doing that anyway.